# Probabilities with Lottery Tickets

Tags: probability

**The Problem:**

Consider a lottery company which determines the outcome of each of their scratcher tickets by flipping a perfect coin where heads means that the scratcher ticket will contain a reward (while tails result in no reward). A lottery shop owner keeps a hundred scratcher tickets in his shop. If a visiting customer selects and *takes* a ticket at random and loses, will the chance of winning for a second customer who also selects a ticket at random increase?

Alternate scenarios to consider:

1. The owner restocks the shop so that there are always a hundred tickets
2. The owner knows how many tickets in his shop will win
3. The customers know how many tickets in the shop will win
4. The tickets are placed in a stack and customers can only take the ticket on top

**My thoughts:**

When I first encountered this problem, it seemed obvious that the chance of each ticket winning should be completely independent as their results are determined by an independent factor. However, after considering alternate scenarios 2 and 3, it also seems as if it is obvious that a second customer should have a higher chance of winning.

Comment: because each ticket wins or loses independently, the odds will not increase - it would be true if the owner had allocated 50 wins and 50 losses to the tickets, but he didn't.  Effectively each ticket is a record of an independent coin toss, buying a ticket views the result of a tossed coin, and each ticket viewed is independent of every other.

Comment: 2 - the odds calculated by the owner change, but to the player they can not be changed by him without info

Comment: 3) Then the probability calculated by the player can change - if there were two cards and it was known one was a winning card - then the customer could buy the second card with a win probability of 1

Comment: 4) This has no effect, there is no way of knowing anything about the top card - an analogy is that it makes no difference which fair coin you choose to make a coin toss

Comment: 1) each remaining ticket has a 50% chance of winning, independent to all others, each new ticket also has a 50% chance of winning independent to any other - the restocking and whether or not a restocked or a remaining card is chosen makes no difference to any probabilities

Comment: In cases (2) and (3), you may move into personal probability: the probability using the information the owner has may be different from the probability using the information the customer has.